# Drop down value selected using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used a drop down list that has four types of values

1.anually
2.semianually
3.quarterly
4.Monthly

Its value always uses `onclick` ICON change, the default value is `anually`. If the user changes it to `semianually` the ICON changes `A` to `s`. This is my select option code:

```
<div class="modal"id="mymodal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="pop-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="pop-info"style="top: 100px;width:220px">
            <div class="pop-header">
                    <button id="Button1" class="pop-closebtn shadow-inset pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                        X</button>
                    <p>&nbsp</p>
                </div>
 <select name="monthlymipfrequency" id="myForm1" >
            <option value="monthly"  name="a"  id="monthly1" >Monthly</option>
            <option value="quarterly"  name="a" id="quarterly1" >Quarterly</option>
            <option value="semianually" name="a"  id="semianually1"  >Semi Anually</option>
            <option value="anually"    name="a" id="anually1" selected  >Anually</option>
          </select>
           <!--     </div>-->

                <div class="pop-footer">
                    <button id="cancel" class="dont-compare shadow-inset" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="trigger1" type="button" class="dont-compare shadow-inset">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have four option values. This my script

```
 var id;
var eve;
var ImageName;
function changeperiod1(event, _id, _src) {
    id = _id;
    eve = event;
    //alert(_id);
    var img = _src.substring(_src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    ImageName = img;
   $('#mymodal1').modal()
    if (ImageName == "A.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#anually1").prop('checked', true);
        $("#semianually1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#quarterly1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly1").prop('checked', false);
    }
    if (ImageName == "Q.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#quarterly1").prop('checked', true);
        $("#anually1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#semianually1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly1").prop('checked', false);

    }
    if (ImageName == "S.png") {
        // alert(ImageName);
        $("#semianually1").prop('checked', true);
        $("#quarterly1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#anually1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly1").prop('checked', false);

    }
    if (ImageName == "M.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#monthly1").prop('checked', true);
        $("#semianually1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#quarterly1").prop('checked', false);
        $("#anually1").prop('checked', false);

    }
    // $('#save').hide();
    $('#trigger1').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#trigger1').addClass('disabledButton');
  }
var value;
$('#myForm1 input').on('change', function () {
    value = $('input[name="a"]:checked', '#myForm1').val();
    $('#trigger1').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#trigger1').removeClass('disabledButton');
});
$('#trigger1').on('click', function () {
    if (value == "anually") {

        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/A.png");


    }
    if (value == "semianually") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/S.png");

    }
    if (value == "quarterly") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/Q.png");

    }
    if (value == "monthly") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/M.png");

    }
    $('#mymodal1').modal('hide');
});
```

It's not working, what mistake did I make? Please help me. My Jsfiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/htcLcu4d/

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your fiddle is not loading jQuery. Also, `.modal()` is not included in jQuery. You need Bootstrap or jQuery UI. I changed your code to use the `.val()` function to update the selected value. I have also changed the fiddle to include jQuery and Bootstrap.

### Updated

**JS:**

```
//popup for Period
var id;
var eve;
var ImageName;

function changeperiod1(event, _id, _src) {
    id = _id;
    eve = event;
    //alert(_id);
    var img = _src.substring(_src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    ImageName = img;
    $('#mymodal1').modal('show');
    if (ImageName == "A.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#myForm1").val('anually');
    }
    if (ImageName == "Q.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#myForm1").val('quarterly');
    }
    if (ImageName == "S.png") {
        // alert(ImageName);
        $("#myForm1").val('semianually');
    }
    if (ImageName == "M.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#myForm1").val('monthly');
    }
    // $('#save').hide();
    $('#trigger1').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#trigger1').addClass('disabledButton');
}
var value;
$('#myForm1').on('change', function(){
    value = $('#myForm1').val();
    $('#trigger1').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#trigger1').removeClass('disabledButton');
});
$('#trigger1').on('click', function () {
    if (value == "anually") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/A.png");
    }
    if (value == "semianually") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/S.png");
    }
    if (value == "quarterly") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/Q.png");
    }
    if (value == "monthly") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/M.png");
    }
    $('#mymodal1').modal('hide');
});
```

### Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/htcLcu4d/7/

Comment: Save button disabled @hopkins-matt. if user change anually Icon also  change  its not change

Comment: save button not Working Please take look your jsfiddle

Comment: I have updated the code to work beyond the issues mentioned in your original question. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct (by clicking the checkmark below the number of votes).